# Pass models on other models C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Im making a text adventure.
in the course of my text adventure i try to seperate Humans, Monster, Attacks etc.
i created a Model folder in which i store Humans, Monsters, weapons, Attacks etc.

Monster Class looks like this

```
public int id {get;set;}
public int health {get;set}
public attacks attack{get;set;}
public Monster()
{
    attacks angriff = new attacks();
}
```

Attacken class looks like this:

```
public int Tackle { get; set; }
public int Beissen { get; set; }
public int Aquaknarre { get; set; }
public int Feuersturm { get; set; }
```

now in my main() i try to create a Monster and try to give them attacks:
and here my skills are ending.
i got the error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.'
laborConsole.Model.Monster._attacken.get returned null.

my main looks like this:

```
Monster vampir = new Monster();
vampir.health=350;
vampir._attacken.Beissen=55;
```

....
My question is, how can i pass my attack model on Monster model?

Comment: As an argument to a method.

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted has several problems:

1. In ctor you create a new `attacks` and assign it to `angriss`... what is angriss?
2. In main you use `vampir._attacken.Beissen=55`; but I don't see any property called `_attacken` in your monster class

I think you should change your code constructor like this

```
public Monster()
{
    attack = new attacks();
}
```

and then in your main you could use

```
vampire.attack.Beissen=55;
```

Property `_attacken` in `vampir` is not initialized (so it's null) and when you try to access one of its properties you get the error.

Just a side note: are you completely sure you want to have `public attacks attack {get;set;}`?
I think it could be wiser having `public attacks attack {get; private set;}`